# Oracle sql to change number format

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to replace number format  with dots and commas to simple decimal number.

Ex: if string is, `25.25.25,00`, it should become `252525.00`

How can this be achieved.

Comment: Why on earth do you store numbers as strings?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm

Comment: @OldProgrammer - the link is to the wrong function. The right function for this type of multiple, simultaneous replacement is `translate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either consecutively apply `REPLACE()` functions as

```
REPLACE(REPLACE('25.25.25,00','.'),',','.')
```

**or**

apply first `TO_NUMBER()` and then `TO_CHAR()` function as

```
TO_CHAR(
        TO_NUMBER('25.25.25,00','999999999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.'''),
       'fm999999999D00'
       )
```

presuming scale has *at most* two digits for all values that you have for the second case.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5b329fe92f5cee6fb770cfae24521b1a)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Use the `translate` function:

```
select translate('25.25.25,00', ',.', '.') as new_str
from   dual
;

NEW_STR  
---------
252525.00
```

This translates "comma" to "period", and "period" to nothing (since the third argument is shorter than the second) - meaning it is simply discarded.